# How to understand the expression "{} == true"?

Tags: javascript

I try to understand the expression `{} == true` following the section `7.2.12` of doc [`Ecma-262`](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

> 9. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`

The result of `ToNumber(true)` is `1`, then

`{} == 1`

> 11. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then
>       return the result of the comparison `ToPrimitive(x) == y`.

I am confused at the `ToPrimitive({})` now.

> 3. If hint is "string", then
>
>    a. Let methodNames be «"toString", "valueOf"».
> 4. Else,
>
>    a. Let methodNames be «"valueOf", "toString"».

**Should `ToPrimitive({})` be interpreted as `{}.toString()` or `{}.valueOf()`?**

Suppose the `toString()` is called.

> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
>   return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`

So `{} == true` could be `ToNumber(ToPrimitive({})) == ToNumber(true)`?

Comment: `methodNames` list is a priority list

Comment: "*could someone give more details*" sounds too broad for SO. What do you want to know?

Comment: @Bergi I get some details from 'Dmitri Pavlutin' answer. You are right, I will update my question.

Comment: Both answers provided are correct and complement each other. As you stated two questions, Felix Kling better answers: `Should ToPrimitive({}) be interpreted as {}.toString() or {}.valueOf()?`; and Dmitri Pavlutin better answers: `So {} == true could be ToNumber(ToPrimitive({})) == ToNumber(true)?`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive) says:

> When `ToPrimitive` is called with no hint, then it generally behaves as if the hint were Number.

Hence, according to the `ToPrimitive` algorithm, `valueOf` is called  first. But since that returns an object, not a primitive value, `toString` will be called second, which returns a string.

> So `{} == true` could be `ToNumber(ToPrimitive({})) == ToNumber(true)`?

Yes, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: Could you please give more details about `ToNumber(ToPrimitive({})) == ToNumber(true)`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? I thought you know what the functions are doing?

Comment: I get some details from @Dmitri Pavlutin answer.

Answer (score 7):

`ToPrimitive({})` first evaluates to `{}.valueOf()`. Because `valueOf()` returns the object itself, the `toString()` method is used.
`{}.toString()` returns `"[object Object]"`, which is compared with `1`. `"[object Object]"` is transformed to a number `NaN` and compared with `1`.
Now operands are the same type Number, and the === operator is used. `NaN === 1` evaluates to `false`.

Formally:

1. `{} == true` (transform `true` to `Number` -> `1`)
2. `{} == 1` (transform {} using `valueOf()`, then `toString()` -> `"[object Object]"`)
3. `"[object Object]" == 1` (transform the `"[object Object]"` to `Number` -> `NaN`)
4. `NaN == 1` (change the operator to `===` because of operands are the same types)
5. `NaN === 1`
6. `false`

**Update:** Check my post [The legend of JavaScript equality operator](http://rainsoft.io/the-legend-of-javascript-equality-operator/) with a lot more details and examples.

Comment: What I mentioned in the question is `==`, not `===`, so `NaN === 1`?

Comment: @zangw, NaN in any comparison return false

Comment: @zangw Because the == transforms first the operands to the same type, and in the end the === is done (NaN and 1 are the same Number type). In simple words when using ==, in the end === is used anyway after transforming to the same types.